# How do I set a namespace prefix to an XAttribute in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap

All,
I want to create a soap envelope xml document eg.

```
<soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"></soap:Envelope>
```

I am using `System.Xml.Linq` to do this but I cannot figure out how to add the `soap` prefix to the `encodingStyle` attribute.

So far, I have this:

```
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope");
XAttribute prefix = new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "soap", ns);
XAttribute encoding = new XAttribute("encodingStyle", "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding");

XElement envelope = new XElement(ns + "Envelope", prefix, encoding);
```

which gives me

```
<soap:Envelope encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"></soap:Envelope>
```

You use `XAttribute` to add a prefix to an element, can I use `XAttribute` to add a prefix to an `XAttribute`??!

thanks, P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Specify the namespace when you create the 'encodingStyle' XAttribute (by using `ns + "encodingStyle"`):

```
XAttribute encoding = new XAttribute(ns + "encodingStyle", "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding");
```

The [two-parameter XAttribute constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336630.aspx) takes an `XName` as the first argument. This can either be constructed implicitly from a `string` (as in the code in your question), or directly by "adding" a `string` to an `XNamespace` to create an `XName` (as above).

Comment: Thanks. Is it just me or is this a really poorly designed API? Some "clever" operator overloading but no constructor overload do the same thing? what?

Comment: Note that the XAttribute constructor takes an `XName`. `string` has an implicit conversion to `XName`, but you can also create one by "adding" an `XNamespace` to a string name. System.Xml.Linq uses operator overloading and implicit/explicit conversion operators extensively; for example, `(int) elem.Attribute("count")` will read the string value of the `count` attribute (on `elem`), parse it as an integer, and return the value. It's not very discoverable, but results in very concise/terse/incomprehensible (delete as appropriate) code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine the XName of your XAttribute with an XNamespace. I know right... Anyhow try this.

```
XNamespace soap = "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope";
XAttribute encoding = new XAttribute(soap + "encodingStyle",
    "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding");
```

Comment: Note that you already have the XNamespace called "ns". I just named it "soap" to make it more clear what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `XName.Get` method to construct the attribute name with a namespace:

```
var xName = XName.Get("myAttributeName", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
var attr = new XAttribute(xName, "myAttributeValue");
```