# Set Root Namespace Prefix in an XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linq-to-xml, xelement

I currently have:

```
XNamespace xmlns = "XSDName";<br>
XNamespace xsi = @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";<br>
XNamespace schemaloc = @"XSDName XSDName.xsd";
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("BaseReport",
    new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", schemaloc),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns+"ns1", xmlns),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi));
```

This gives me:

```
BaseReport xsi:schemaLocation="XSDName XSDName .xsd" xmlns:ns1="XSDName" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

How can I have `BaseReport` read `ns1:BaseReport`?

Comment: Can you add the assignment for the variables `xsi`, `schemaloc` and `xmlns` to your code sample?

Comment: After doing additional research, I don't believe that you can use a namespace in the root element. The namespace is defined as an attribute of the root element and would be undefined for the root itself. You can read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4985974/299327).

Comment: But, when I use something like XMLSpy to generate a sample xml from the XSD's it uses "ns1:BaseReport" as the header tag...

Comment: And it doesn't declare the `ns1` namespace at a higher level? Where does it declare this namespace?

Comment: The XMLSpy generator generates an xml with an xml header the same as what I'm looking to do with code, I just don't know how to get the "ns1:BaseReport" portion in code so that it validates properly.

Comment: I found an example of what you are talking about in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4406330/299327), but I am still trying to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code will give you the output that you want. The key is adding the defined namespace before the name and letting .NET figure out the correct prefix.

```
XNamespace xmlns = "XSDName";
XNamespace xsi = @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
XNamespace schemaloc = @"XSDName XSDName.xsd";
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement(xmlns + "BaseReport",
    new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", schemaloc),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns1", xmlns),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi)));
```

Comment: Ah, yeah I got this from the previous link you sent +/- some fiddling. [Page didn't refresh, derp.] Thanks so much!